# 403.14 forbidden error for controller named "security" with IIS 8.0 Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In my project there is a controller named `Security` and it has a default page called `Index.cshtml` as does every other controller in my project. However, while every other index page for every other controller works, going to `http://localhost:[port]/security/` generates the following error...

[image]

Even after adding the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`to my config and setting it to true the error still persists. And there's a bonus. Same deal with switching to VS 2012 development server from IIS Express. But oddly, I can enter `http://localhost:[port]/security/user?id=[id]` and get back a correctly formatted user profile with no problem.

So what could possibly be going on? Am I bumping into some sort of reserved word or setting and need to disable it? How can I make my default security page work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing slash from the security endpoint?   try `http://localhost:[port]/security` instead.

Comment: @jeffdot, yes, it doesn't do anything. The trailing slash would just tell it to go to the index page but that's not happening here. I think there's some hangup over a directory called "security".

Comment: I've tested this and it works fine. There must be some other code here that is causing the problem. Have you changed the default routes or registered a global filter?

Comment: @DavidG, no, the only thing I changed is enabled lower case uris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so after much investigation, I found an old "security" folder which was excluded from my project but not deleted. IIS Express was apparently either trying to map the controller's view folder to that directory or the virtual directory it set up somehow ended up pointing to this folder. After removing it, everything worked like a charm.